# rake task via cron problem loading rubygems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rake, scheduled-tasks, delayed-job

I have managed to get a cron job to run a rake task by doing the following:

```
cd /home/myusername/approotlocation/ && /usr/bin/rake sendnewsletter RAILS_ENV=development
```

i have checked with `which ruby` and `which rake` to make sure the paths are correct (from bash)

the job looks like it wants to run as i get the following email from the cron daemon when it completes

```
Missing these required gems:
      chronic  
      whenever  
      searchlogic  
      adzap-ar_mailer  
      twitter  
      gdata  
      bitly  
      ruby-recaptcha

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.22 at /usr/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.3.5 at /home/myusername/gems, /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
(in /home/myusername/approotlocation)
```

my custom rake file within lib/tasks is as follows:

```
task :sendnewsletter => :environment do
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'chronic'  
 require 'whenever'  
 require 'searchlogic'  
 require 'adzap-ar_mailer'  
 require 'twitter'  
 require 'gdata'  
 require 'bitly'  
 require 'ruby-recaptcha'
   @recipients = Subscription.all(:conditions => {:active => true})
    for user in @recipients
      Email.send_later(:deliver_send_newsletter,user)
    end
end
```

with or without the require items, it still gives me the same error ...

can anyone shed some light on this? or alternatively advise me on how to make a custom file within the script directory that will run this function (I already have a cron job working that will run and process all my delayed_jobs.

After Jonathans suggestion below I ran

> env

as a cron job on its own and received the following output:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
MAILTO=myemailaddress
USER=myusername
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
PWD=/home/myusername
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/myusername
LOGNAME= myusername
_=/usr/bin/env
```

does this mean it's not loading the ruby files properly?
 ....
also took Jonathans advice and produced the following `cron.sh` file

```
#!/bin/sh
date
echo "Executing Matenia Rake Task"
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
cd /home/myusername/approotlocation/
rake sendnewsletter
```

still getting the missing gems notice ... 
Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest way to fix this (but kind of a shotgun approche) is from your shell type

env | grep PATH

Then take this output and add it your crontab for that user

so it would look something like this

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user    command
42 6 * * *        root    job1
47 6 * * 7        root    job2
52 6 1 * *        root    job3
```

Just make sure your gems's are inside of that path

Comment: There was alot of difficulty in updating the file with it inserting text where it shouldnt have been ... cannot complete this option unfortunately ... thanks for trying :)

Comment: I still think this is a path issue, just using /usr/bin and /bin is a fairly small and narrow path. From YOUR shell type echo $PATH and this is what you should make the path.

Comment: yeh i put that in the cron.sh file i wanted to run to do the rake task .. but unfortunately, it does not want to load the applications' installed gems ... i must be missing something soooo simple ...

Comment: put the path at the top of your cron file

crontab -e

add your path, then your job and let me know how that works.

Comment: as i said, i couldnt do this because the editor in the terminal was going nuts and not doing what i wanted it to do ... im guessing this would have worked ... so i will mark it as the solution.. but could not complete it due to editing difficulties (i guess i need to brush up on this before i do it again)

Comment: +1 I had the same problem and the "env | grep PATH" trick worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When cron runs, it executes with a very minimal environment. Try running a cron job that just does `env` or `which ruby`, and you may see that your PATH is not the same as your interactive shell path. You'll need to specifically set the PATH in `.bash_profile` or another shell startup file.

Comment: updated my post with ENV output ... maybe it would be better if I made a .sh script .... added that coding to above as well ...

Answer (score 0):

I got around all of this by making a custom script/file and running that through cron. I dont know how, but it managed to work ...
Thanks for all the efforts.